# How do I change a CSS property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, background

I have green circle in my html file (index.html) and I want to change the color by clicking a button which runs the JavaScript (change.js).

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    #circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: green;
    }

</style>

<h1>Change Colors</h1>

<div id="circle"></div>

<p>
<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="change.js">Change Color</button>
</div>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is change.js:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("circle").style.background="red";
}
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between server-side code and client-side code.  You need to learn Javascript.

Comment: the idea is correct but you are still far in the code ... you need to learn about ajax request

Comment: I answered my own question. I had to change onclick in the html to equal "myFunction()".